# How to alter css class once found in chrome console

Tags: php, css, wordpress, google-chrome, modal-dialog

Not sure how best to title this. I have a button that creates a modal popup for a job application form in WP Job Manager. I wish to duplicate this button on the same page which I have done, however my new button not only creates the modal but also loads the same application form on the page itself at the same time, this is not intended. The popup/modal is using Magnific Popup. Using Chrome console I found the issue that my new button is using a class without 'mfp-hide' at the end of it whereas the first button does have this.

By adding mfp-hide to the end of the class for that button in the Chrome console I solve the issue - the modal then loads correctly and the modal content does not load on the page. My issue is how/where to allocate a new class with mfp-hide at the end of it in my files. I am used to modifying class properties in child themes but not sure how to add this property/replace the class type. If you look here https://boolerang.co.uk/job/birch-creative-limited-permanent-full-stack-developer/ for example and right click inspect the top apply button then do the same with the lower apply button you can see the missing 'mfp-hide' on the lower. Clicking the lower button will show the problem.

In content-single-job_listing.php I added this to generate the second button:

```
<?php if ( candidates_can_apply() ) : ?>
<?php get_job_manager_template( 'job-application.php' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

job-application.php contains:

```
<?php if ( $apply = get_the_job_application_method() ) :
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-job-manager-job-application' );
?>
<div class="job_application application">
    <?php do_action( 'job_application_start', $apply ); ?>

    <input type="button" class="application_button button" value="<?php 
esc_attr_e( 'Apply for job', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?>" />

    <div class="application_details">
        <?php
            /**
             * job_manager_application_details_email or 
job_manager_application_details_url hook
             */
            do_action( 'job_manager_application_details_' . $apply->type, 
$apply );
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php do_action( 'job_application_end', $apply ); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The Chrome console for the original button shows:

```
<div class="application_details modal mfp-hide" id="apply-overlay" 
style="display: block;">
<form class="job-manager-application-form job-manager-form" method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://boolerang.co.uk/job/birch- 
creative-limited-permanent-full-stack-developer/">
```

I wish to change the class associated with the lower button to include the 'mfp-hide' which the Magnific Popup says is required in their documentation to have the desired effect. I don't know which file I need to alter to do this as it's not the button class which would be much easier. Any suggestions of where to edit to get this included would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have only shown an opening `<div>` tag and an opening `<form>` tag - not sure how that is supposed to constitute a “button” in the first place, there must presumably be some more to this. And not really sure what you are asking here either. If `get_job_manager_template( 'job-application.php' );` is what gets your second button output, then presumably you’d want to start looking in that very template to see what’s going on there?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes I had looked into those files but didn't see anything obvious - edited my answer to include that file now, didn't originally for fear was too much to read.

Comment: You want to get `<div class="application_details modal mfp-hide"` in your end result, and this contains `<div class="application_details"` already, so … add the extra class(es) there?

Comment: Yes! superb, thank you. I wasn't aware I could just add it on in that way and thought it might affect the top button adversely but it's all working as a modified template in the child theme. Thank you. (That site example was not mine I just found it had the same problem as I was having building mine and happened to be live.)